# How to change the login form for Unified Service Desk?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, unified-service-desk

New on Dynamics CRM 2013, Unified Service Desk, aka USD, is a composite application framework for the development of call center and, of course, service desk, applications.

The application has it's own login form. While very flexible for development scenarios, it's not what I'd expect to have on a production environment - for instance, it asks for the address of the CRM instance that you are going to connect to.

So far, I haven't found any way to change this login form.

[image]

Comment: This form is only shown the first time a user runs the USD application, after that the values entered are reused. That would indicate they must be stored in a config file, most likely the app.config. I would do some research and see if you can find a way to default the connection string. Note, if this is a CRM Live instance it will be tricky because most likely your users need to key in their passwords.

Comment: @Nicknow This is not what I'd like to have in a production scenario. First of all, saving the password may present a security concern - call centers are usually contractors so I have no control over their environment, which mean that Windows logins can be shared between agents. Second of all, selecting the address is not user friendly this "advanced" option is thrown at the user, even preceding the user name. Being able to customize or completely replace it is a must for real world projects.

Comment: There are organizations using USD in real world call centers - so it is certainly doable for some organizations. That said, if it doesn't meet your requirements then you'll have to build your own. Btw, I don't think the password is saved - the user, if I recall correctly, is prompted for their password when it is needed.

Comment: @Nicknow, I expect most organizations to be displeased by such a login form. One of my clients certainly is. Consider that most call center operations are outsourced. Now, building my own is the problem itself - there's no way of replacing just that from USD, and building a full USD from scratch... is, of course, insane. Also, it *does* store the user password (at Windows Credential Store), which may be a problem if the organization does not have direct control over the infrastructure, so that it doesn't have guarantees that each user have his own login to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The login form is of the Unified Service Desk client application, and cannot be changed. Moreover, Unified Service Desk requires an instance of Microsoft Dynamics CRM, so the login form will always prompt you to specify the connection information to a CRM instance where you have deployed the core USD solutions (DynamicsBase and UII). The things that you can customize in the agent desktop are the features and layouts within the application.

You can however configure the sign-in experience to pre-populate values in the sign-in dialog box. For more information, see the **Configure sign-in information** section in the [Connect to CRM instance using the Unified Service Desk client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn646904.aspx) topic.

Unified Service Desk uses the XRM tooling common login control to define the login form. If you are building your "own" Windows client application for CRM, you can use the XRM tooling common login control, which provides The code for CRM authentication, credential storage and retrieval, and diagnostic logging so that you can quickly leverage these capabilities in your Windows client applications for CRM. More information about this: [Use the XRM tooling common login control in your client applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn689071.aspx).

Thanks,

Vivek

Answer (score 1):

There was a login control provided in XRM.Tooling.connector namespace. This might be a start point to give it a thought..

Please refer to ..https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn689071.aspx

Comment: Answers should be self contained and not links to external ressources.

Answer (score 1):

You can default the configuration information for the connection experience in USD. The documentation on how to do that is in the Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector SDK Doc's.   Effectively you need to add the default settings to the UnifiedServiceDesk.exe.config before you provide the client to your users.  that will preload the dialog with connection information, and in the case of OnPremise / AD it can attempt an autologin and never show this dialog.

Also, 
Regarding the comment above about storing passwords for login.  USD does do this. it uses the Windows Credential vault to store the Password data and other encrypted stores to store other aspects of its configuration.  The Windows Credential vault can be managed by Windows Admin's and flushed if necessary.

You can also tell USD to not store passwords with a setting in the UnifiedServiceDesk.exe.config file. The byproduct of which is that the user is required to key their password each and every time the shell connects to CRM.

Comment: MattB, can you provide a link to said documentation. I'm looking at the chm that comes with the SDK but can't find the information.